# CHROME-EXTENSION: chrome.runtime.lastError no tab with id error

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project that creates a google chrome extension and I am using chrome API's in it. Now, I am trying to work my handleTabUpdate function when tab is updated. However, I am getting `Unchecked runtime.lastError: No tab with id: 60`

How can I fixed that? Here is my code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(handleTabUpdate)
```

```
function handleTabUpdate(tabId, info) {
  if (info.status === 'loading') {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET_TABHOSTS' })
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (activeTab) => {
      if (tabId === store.getState().currentTab['id']) {
        store.dispatch({ type: 'ACTIVE_TAB', payload: activeTab })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the tab you are looking for was closed, so when you try to get it by `id` the operation fails.
To avoid the error, my suggestion is to first [query](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-query) all tabs and see if a tab with a specific `id` exists in the result. If it does, run `chrome.tabs.get()` and with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped up against this issue in MV3 and I've tooled a solution that allows a bit more ease when working with tabs.

**Functions**

```
const handleRuntimeError = () => {
    const error = chrome.runtime.lastError;
    if (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};

const safeGetTab = async (tabId) => {
    const tab = await chrome.tabs.get(parseInt(tabId));
    try {
        handleRuntimeError();
        return tab;
    } catch (e){
        console.log('safeGetTab', e.message);
    }
    return {};
};
```

**Implementation**

```
(async () => {
  // assumes some tabId
  const tab = await safeGetTab(tabId);
})()
```

This will return a value no matter what. It will either return the tab object or an empty object. Then you can can just do some basic checking in your script to decide how you want to handle that. In my case I can simply ignore the action that would have been taken on that tab and move on.